# Check is new day/midnight java android

Tags: java, android

I have timer witch is triggered periodically every 30 minutes - how to check on each trigger is current time midnight (is it new day) ?

I tried something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date = new Date();
Date currTime = parser.parse( parser.format( date ) );
```

but I am not sure how to check if it is midnight, because I don't know does it use 24:00:00 or 00:00:00 for midnight clock, so I can use it and then check if current time is between midnight and lets say midnight and one minute like this :

```
if( currTime.after(midnight) && currTime.before(midnight and one minute) ){...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

if(hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds < 1800){
    // Day changed since last task
}
```

Comment: can you just help me a little bit, how is your code supposed to work? I am not sure I understand it

Comment: As your trigger loop every 30 minutes, this code will check if the time is between midnight and midnight and a half. So put this code in your trigger, and inside the if, write the code you want to be executed if day changed since last time the loop ran.